# How do I allow a bold element to remain at the start of a string and add an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to bold the only word in the array and none of the numbers. When I use this:

```
document.getElementById("gradesArray").innerHTML = grades;
```

It replaces the **`Grades:`**  completely and just has the array. Knocks that out. I don't know how to either, 1.) allow the **`Grades:`**  to remain without being affected, or 2.) add **`Grades:`**  bolded at the beginning of an array without any of the numbers getting affected. Can anyone help? Here is the full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .margin {
      margin-left: 80px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p class="margin"><b>Got </b></p><input type="number" class="margin" id="iGotThis" name="number">
  <p class="margin"><b> out of </b></p><input type="number" class="margin" id="outOfThis" name="number">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" class="margin" onclick="perFunction()">
  <br>
  <br>
  <p id="gradesArray"><b>Grades: </b></p>

  <script>
    const multiplier = 10000;
    let rounded = 0;


    var input = document.getElementById("outOfThis");
    var input2 = document.getElementById("iGotThis");
    let perMade = 0;
    const grades = [];
    var arrayList = document.getElementById("gradesArray").innerHTML;

    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {

      let iGotThis = document.getElementById("iGotThis").value;
      let outOfThis = document.getElementById("outOfThis").value;
      perMade = iGotThis / outOfThis;
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("submit").click();
      }
    });

    input2.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {

      let iGotThis = document.getElementById("iGotThis").value;
      let outOfThis = document.getElementById("outOfThis").value;
      perMade = iGotThis / outOfThis;
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("submit").click();
      }
    });


    function perFunction() {
      let rounded = Math.round(perMade * multiplier) / 100;
      grades.push(arrayList + " " + rounded + "%");
      document.getElementById("gradesArray").innerHTML = grades;
      documentgetElementById("iGotThis").value = 0;
      documentgetElementById("outOfThis").value = 0;
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are replacing the entire HTML inside of <p>, just add to it instead. 
`document.getElementById("gradesArray").innerHTML += grades;`

Comment: Well, yes. `innerHTML = grades` replaces _all_ of the HTML of that element with the new HTML. Maybe have two spans in there. One for the label, the other for the updated HTML.

Comment: You could nest a `span` that you'll ultimately edit `<p><b>Grades: </b><span id="gradesArray" /></p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another `span` within `p` and shift your `gradesArray` id to `span` instead

```
<p><b>Grades: </b><span id="gradesArray"></span></p>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .margin {
      margin-left: 80px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p class="margin"><b>Got </b></p><input type="number" class="margin" id="iGotThis" name="number">
  <p class="margin"><b> out of </b></p><input type="number" class="margin" id="outOfThis" name="number">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" class="margin" onclick="perFunction()">
  <br>
  <br>
  <p><b>Grades: </b><span id="gradesArray"></span></p>

  <script>
    const multiplier = 10000;
    let rounded = 0;


    var input = document.getElementById("outOfThis");
    var input2 = document.getElementById("iGotThis");
    let perMade = 0;
    const grades = [];
    var arrayList = document.getElementById("gradesArray").innerHTML;

    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {

      let iGotThis = document.getElementById("iGotThis").value;
      let outOfThis = document.getElementById("outOfThis").value;
      perMade = iGotThis / outOfThis;
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("submit").click();
      }
    });

    input2.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {

      let iGotThis = document.getElementById("iGotThis").value;
      let outOfThis = document.getElementById("outOfThis").value;
      perMade = iGotThis / outOfThis;
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("submit").click();
      }
    });


    function perFunction() {
      let rounded = Math.round(perMade * multiplier) / 100;
      grades.push(arrayList + " " + rounded + "%");
      document.getElementById("gradesArray").innerHTML = grades;
      document.getElementById("iGotThis").value = 0;
      document.getElementById("outOfThis").value = 0;
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

*P/s: you have a syntax problem with `documentgetElementById`. I fixed it for you too*

Comment: Thank you, it works! Also, I notice that they finally both reset to ```0```, and if I connect the dots that is probably the ```documentgetElementById```, so thanks for that as well! (I don't have a console log so I can't see those errors. I can't get apps like Notepad++ or anything.)

Comment: You're welcome!~ Enjoy your coding life :D @LandonWallick

Answer (score 2):

I would move the bold label out of the `gradesArray` element.

```html
<b>Grades: </b>
<p id="gradesArray"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3 big changes were:

1. `document.getElementById("gradesArray").innerHTML = "<b>Grades:</b> " + grades.join(", ");` so you can take the array and join all the elements together.
2. You had a syntax error in your initial code; `documentgetElementById` as opposed to `document.getElementById`.
3. You don't need `arrayList`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .margin {
      margin-left: 80px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p class="margin"><b>Got </b></p><input type="number" class="margin" id="iGotThis" name="number">
  <p class="margin"><b> out of </b></p><input type="number" class="margin" id="outOfThis" name="number">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" class="margin" onclick="perFunction()">
  <br>
  <br>
  <p id="gradesArray"><b>Grades: </b></p>

  <script>
    const multiplier = 10000;
    let rounded = 0;


    var input = document.getElementById("outOfThis");
    var input2 = document.getElementById("iGotThis");
    let perMade = 0;
    const grades = [];
    var arrayList = document.getElementById("gradesArray").innerHTML;

    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {

      let iGotThis = document.getElementById("iGotThis").value;
      let outOfThis = document.getElementById("outOfThis").value;
      perMade = iGotThis / outOfThis;
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("submit").click();
      }
    });

    input2.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {

      let iGotThis = document.getElementById("iGotThis").value;
      let outOfThis = document.getElementById("outOfThis").value;
      perMade = iGotThis / outOfThis;
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("submit").click();
      }
    });


    function perFunction() {
      let rounded = Math.round(perMade * multiplier) / 100;
      //grades.push(arrayList + " " + rounded + "%");
      grades.push(rounded + "%");
      document.getElementById("gradesArray").innerHTML = "<b>Grades:</b> " + grades.join(", ");
      document.getElementById("iGotThis").value = 0;
      document.getElementById("outOfThis").value = 0;
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but I already got an answer.

Comment: @LandonWallick thats fine. Whichever was most helpful for you.